# Kubectl always returns a error: yaml: mapping values are not allowed in this context

Tags: yaml, kubernetes, kubectl

Kubectl command alway returns this error yaml: line 2: mapping values are not allowed in this context. Even when i call normal version command, config command, etc. Not sure whats causing this.

```
tessact@tessact-sys-1:~$ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"4",
GitVersion:"v1.4.4",
GitCommit:"3b417cc4ccd1b8f38ff9ec96bb50a81ca0ea9d56",
GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2016-10-21T02:48:38Z",
GoVersion:"go1.6.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
error: yaml: line 2: mapping values are not allowed in this context


tessact@tessact-sys-1:~/[some path]$ kubectl create -f kubernetes_configs/frontend.yaml
error: yaml: line 2: mapping values are not allowed in this context
```

The only yaml file i used is

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ReplicationController
metadata:
  name: frontend
  labels:
    name: frontend
spec:
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: frontend
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: trigger
        # Replace  with your project ID or use `make template`
        image: asia.gcr.io/trigger-backend/trigger-backend

        # This setting makes nodes pull the docker image every time before
        # starting the pod. This is useful when debugging, but should be turned
        # off in production.
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080


apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: frontend
  labels:
    name: frontend
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    name: frontend
```

Whatever I try with **kubectl** it returns this error. What should I do to solve this?

```
> tessact@tessact-sys-1:~/developer/trigger-backend-dev/trigger-backend$
> kubectl get service error: yaml: line 2: mapping values are not
> allowed in this context
```

Output of :

```
strace kubectl version
```

is [here](http://pastebin.com/E53yHrwD)

Comment: You should correct your YAML. You might be using tab characters, remove those, and then check for correct indentation. Please replace the screenshots in your posts with text (so it can be indexed) and include the relevant lines of your YAML file (from the beginning to at least line 3).

Comment: how does yaml file affect "kubectl version" command

Comment: Have you tried those URLs by hand? Which one gives something back that looks like a broken YAML file? What exactly is the content of the broken file?

Comment: It seems yaml syntax error in my case, use any online yaml linter to check for errors.

Comment: for me the reason was that i had 'replicas:1' instead of 'replicas: 1', that one space was causing error, be really careful and precise writing yaml by hand

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That the version command already throws an error indicates that there is some default YAML file that gets loaded.

You can use `strace kubectl version` to see what file was opened, hopefully this is done just before `kubectl` throws the error. I assume there is some global config that it reads (or alternatively a default file in your current directory).

It is of course sloppy programming in kubernetes not to catch such an error, and display the name of the file, and then re-raise the error.

Comment: I have attached the output of strace kubectl version

Comment: there was gitlab running at port 8080 once i stopped it the error went away. I really don't know how that was related to any yaml file. but since you told to try the url's from strace i was able to solve it.

Comment: @StarLord, @Anthon, same here, i had a container running in the background - and the error shown by `strace kubectl version` command was in fact the first letters of a `console.log` statement printed by the container that was running. I don't understand how this 2 things are related - but i deleted the container and then it worked with no problem... :)

Comment: really weird in 2022. why would kubectl connect to a docker container running in port 8080 without me specifying anything about it

Answer (score 8):

Most of the time  when you get an error like this (speaking in general and meaningful terms) it is either because of :-

1). A syntax error (in your case it is not) in the yaml file.

2). Or like the error says "mapping values are not allowed in this context". It means that the keys/values you have used in the yaml, may be syntactically right but not semantically.

Comment: In my case I had missed a space after - array notation which lead to exact same error elsewhere. kubectl's error reporting is one amongst the worst I have seen

Comment: In my case, I had accidentally indented a key to the left, which made everything below it look like its keys. But the key itself also had a value, hence the mapping error.

Comment: In my case, I forgot a colon at the end of the line before the reported line

Answer (score 4):

Since you're getting the error even upon running `kubectl version`, I'd say you've got a yaml syntax error in your kubeconfig file, located at `~/.kube/config` by default.

You could validate its content using a yaml validator like [this one](http://www.yamllint.com/).

Comment: I checked my config file with YAMLlint. It was a valid YAML. Thanks for the answer. But the problem was something else which i still can't understand

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you have completed the step:

```
mkdir -p $HOME/.kube  
sudo cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/.kube/config
sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.kube/config
```

Even as root user.

I also wasn't able to see version from

```
kubectl version
```

Comment: This. You get this error when you don't have $HOME/.kube/config file existing.

Answer (score 4):

Just to add... 
I have seen this error today after performing a copy/paste operation into my YAML file. The process brought in some whitespace characters that `kubectl` could not decipher.

If you are unsure, paste the YAML into a text editor first that will show all non-visible characters and make sure they are consistent with the rest of your YAML file.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue while executing some Kubernetes basic commands like. kubectl get ns , kubectl get pods, etc...

Solution:

try to stop the minikube cluster and then start again

Answer (score 0):

Just follow these steps, worked for me and found them as the fastest solutions out there:

If you are a regular user (non root):

```
mkdir -p $HOME/.kube
sudo cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/.kube/config 
sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/•kube/config
```

Alternatively, if you are the root user, you can run:

```
export KUBECONFIG=/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf
```